# How to remove windows 7 from windows 8 dual-boot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-8.1

I installed Windows 8.1 on the same hard disk partition as windows 7.
Now I have this problem - I cannot remove Windows 7 from this boot screen.
How to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was able to find documentation by doing a quick search [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542273(v=vs.85).aspx). Just remove the Windows 7 entry after you read all of the linked pages on the website I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run cmd as administrator.

Type **bcdedit** and identify your installation by looking at the description element.
You then right-click on the cmd screen and select *mark* and make your selection on the code show in the identifier element and press ENTER.

Then execute the command by typing bcdedit /delete and right clicking on the same line. If successful, it should paste the identifier.